# Numba printing information regarding Nvidia driver to python console when using its Cuda module. How to suppress this?

Tags: python, numba

I have found that Numba is printing information regarding my Nvidia driver to my python console when using its Cuda module. For example, when using

```
numba.cuda.to_device(SOME_ARRAY)
```

for the first time,

> INFO - 2020-12-21 19:16:22,163 - driver - init

is printed in red to my console. When using it any other time,

> INFO - DATE TIME - driver - add pending dealloc: cuMemFree_v2
> NUM_BYTES bytes

is printed. For example:

> INFO - 2020-12-21 19:18:34,473 - driver - add pending dealloc:
> cuMemFree_v2 729120 bytes

Is there any way in which I could prevent Numba from printing this information?

_ _

As recommended in the comments, I have already tried setting

```
sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, "w") 

sys.stderr = open(os.devnull, "w")
```

before running `numba.cuda.to_device()`, but this did not solve the issue.

I have also looked into Numba's environmental variables and have found nothing that solves the issue. To be specific, I have tried setting

```
os.environ['NUMBA_CUDA_LOG_LEVEL'] = str(logging.NOTSET)
```

and

```
os.environ['NUMBA_CUDA_LOG_LEVEL'] = str(logging.DEBUG)
```

And none of the two solved the issue. I have also tried setting

```
numba.config.CUDA_LOG_LEVEL = logging.NOTSET
```

and

```
numba.config.CUDA_LOG_LEVEL = logging.DEBUG
```

but once again this did not solve the issue.

Comment: You would need to suppress stdout as it's probably a print from the kernal. Without having the kernal code infront of me I cannot confirm. Try `sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, "w")
sys.stderr = open(os.devnull, "w")` just before it prints and then restore it with`sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
sys.stderr = sys.__stderr__` after

Comment: Looking online I found several `Environment Variables` that change how `Numba` behaves. I'm sure one of [These](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/envvars.html) once changed will disable the printing. To set an `environment var` in python use `os.environ[ARGUMENT_NAME: str] = ARGUMENT_VALUE: int`

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. So I have tried setting sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, "w") and sys.stderr = open(os.devnull, "w") before moving arrays to the GPU, and sys.__stdout__ and sys.stderr = sys.__stderr__ after everything is done. Sadly, this did not solve the issue.

Comment: I have also tried setting os.environ['NUMBA_CUDA_LOG_LEVEL'] = str(logging.DEBUG) and os.environ['NUMBA_CUDA_LOG_LEVEL'] = str(logging.NOTSET) at the beginning of my program but this also did not help. Finally, I have also tried numba.config.CUDA_LOG_LEVEL = logging.NOTSET and numba.config.CUDA_LOG_LEVEL = logging.DEBUG and this also did not work. I had a look at the remainder of the environmental variables from numba and they did not seem to be relevant.

Comment: Those messages don't come from the NVIDIA driver. They come from within Numba

Comment: I thought so as well as they do not appear when I use PyCuda. Is there anything I can do to prevent them from being printed?

Answer (score 1):

After some time, I have found a solution to this problem. As hinted by talonmies in the comments above, these messages come from the Numba logger. On my machine, the logging level was set to "INFO" and Numba was printing directly to the console. To suppress the printing of information, add the following to your python program:

```
import logging
numba_logger = logging.getLogger('numba')
numba_logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)  # Or any other desired level that has a value above that of "INFO".
```